# An Easy way to Deploy an MVC App to a Desktop Machine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, mono

I have an interesting situation where I need to deploy an ASP.NET MVC app to a (pseudo-boss's) local desktop machine so they can run it locally for data entry purposes.  What would be the best way to get the app running on a vista machine without Visual Studio installed?

Ideally, It would be a one click that started a development web server and opened the page up in the browser.

I considered installing Visual Web Developer and then tricking it's dev web server into running the app, or even installing mono, since it has the nice 'start xsp here' feature that even a non-technical person can understand.  The big thing is that this person is not very technical, so it needs to be easy for them to start and stop the application.

Comment: For posterity:  Mono didn't handle this.

Comment: You should have a dev environment that other's can use/test. This allows you to continue local development without messing up the latest  release for testing/QA/demos etc.

Comment: Theoretically, that would be a wonderful plan.  I've looked into getting this sort of thing setup, but in the corporate environment I'm in, that's simply not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need IIS installed, which should be available for Vista. Then just set up a working directory and put your app there, it's not 1 click but maybe.,.. 5.. :)

Comment: 4 hours later, and four hours of work, I realize that you are correct, and I'm off to make it right.

Comment: To add: IIS 7.0 is part of Vista starting with Home Premium. It is not Part of Home Basic.

Answer (score 3):

What about the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/channel/products/WebPlatformInstaller.aspx)? You'd still have to add your own application, but it takes care of .NET, IIS, and dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like UltiDev Cassini: http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/ and build your own installer to set everything up for your user?